# How to change border of a selected item in Google Chart

Tags: graph, charts, line

[My LineChart graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOPwQ.png)

That's my Line Chart. In the photo, y pushed Pereira, and his line is converted to another style. How can I change that style when I push another Name?

Comment: It would help if you provided us with the code that's generating this graph - or at the very least tagged the programming language. I'm flagging this as unclear because we can't possibly help without those details.

Comment: The code is very big...I use it in javascript. I think is not necessary to display my code